# How Can I set data to class by using spring controller

Tags: spring, spring-boot

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class RosterTest {
   
    @JsonProperty(value = "department")
    private String department;
    @JsonProperty(value = "section")
    private String section;
    
   Getter and Setter
}
```

if I have one class and that I want to set data to class and that list all this data to controller spring

Comment: This class is sufficient, in your controller, use this RosterTest with @RequestBody annotation and from CURL/Postman, make sure you form a JSON with department and section as key and hit